# How to wait for initialization while keeping the UI responsive

Tags: android

I have an android application.  In the initialization of component, it takes a lot of time to initialize. To make the app responsive. I moved its initialization code off the GUI thread to some worker thread. The result of this is that the GUI won't encounter the so called ANR (Application not responding) problem, but the downside is that if I used the component that is not completely initialized, there would be a null pointer exception. I know it can be solved by checking a boolean variable that indicates the initialization is completed and allow the user to use the component only when it is done, but it's not wise since the user cannot not do anything but wait before that.

So my question is that is there any popular smart trick to cover up this background initialization detail. and make user see/do something else while waiting for the initialization to complete without even becoming aware of it?

Comment: You could show some nice animations or wait dialog

Comment: any pointer to materials that walk me through the making of animations when booting my application?

Comment: Here's a nice [link](http://www.onlymobilepro.com/2013/01/16/android-beginner-creating-splash-screen/) to a tutorial on how to make a splas screen. And another [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App)

Comment: Problem is: the component is initialized in my main activity. If I added a splash screen/activity before that. the component is still initialized after the splash screen. How can I show a splash screen while initializing my component in main activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). In addition, read this tutorial [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) to learn how to use AysnTask with UI